# toggle phone's state from ringing mode to vibration mode

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, phone-state-listener

I want to develop an android app which on shake changes the phone state from sound mode to vibration mode to silent mode. I am not getting the way to read the phone's state. how to do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an hint here : 
[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

To get mode :

```
 myAudioManager.getRingerMode();
```

and then (to change mode )

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Mode list [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)